# Column layout with one column filling up width and another shrinking with overflow

Tags: html, css, layout

How to make a layout with multiple columns, where one column takes up the remaing horizontal space, another column being as wide as its content or smaller and the rest of the columns being as wide as their content?

This is how it should look like:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|As wide as content | May shrink | Fill up remaining width          | As wide as content| 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The whole thing should also fill the full width!

I tried with the following:

HTML:

```
<div class='container'>
  <div></div>
  <div class='mayShrink'></div>
  <div class='fillUp'></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div { 
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.container {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.mayShrink {
  overflow:hidden;
}
.fillUp {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Support for IE8 is required.
Can somebody help out?

Comment: try this - http://jsfiddle.net/bpwoss5h/

Comment: Can you explain how you want the `.mayShrink` element to behave?  what determine's its width? and how is it different from the child `div`'s that shrink-to-fit (wide as content)?

Comment: @MaryMelody The mayShrink column should shrink regardless of its content when there is not enough space for all columns

Comment: @MarcAudet If I shrink the container, the fillUp element should shrink first until it fits its content. Then the mayShrink column should shrink until it is 0px wide.

Comment: @daniatic not exactly what you want but try this - http://jsfiddle.net/mmvnxcou/

Comment: @MaryMelody Thx, already had the same approach but the problem is that the mayshrink column shouldn't shrink if the fillUp Column still can shrink to fit its content